# Google Analytics Click to Call event to AMP

Tags: google-analytics, amp-html

I’m using native mode

How can I change the code below to the AMP version?

```
onclick="gtag('event','Click to call',{'event_category':'Call tracking','event_label':'Mobile header'});"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <script type="application/json">
    {
      "vars": {
        "gtag_id": "<GA_TRACKING_ID>",
        "config": {
          "<GA_TRACKING_ID>": {}
        }
      },
      "triggers": {
        "button": {
          "selector": "#the-button",
          "on": "click",
          "vars": {
            "event_name": "login",
            "method": "Google",
            "event_category": "Call tracking",
            "event_label": "Mobile header"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
```

Documentation: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/amp-analytics/#complete_example